# How to renumber a sorted column to start from zero in Excel

Tags: microsoft-excel

I have 2 columns of numbers in excel. After sorting them, I want to convert  the numbers to sorted numbers from zero, which the minimum number converts to 0, second number converts to 1 and ... . For example I have these two columns:

[image]

and I want a result like this:

[image]

Can anybody please help me?!

Thanks

Comment: The example doesn't make sense. Can you post a screen shot?

Comment: Do the numbers in the result correspond to the ordering of the unique values in both columns? Like `{1001,1002,1003,2000}` --> `{0,1,2,3}`?

Answer (score 3):

Assuming your data is (as shown) in *A1:B3*

1. In *D1*, enter
   `=SUMPRODUCT((A1>$A$1:$B$3)/COUNTIF($A$1:$B$3,$A$1:$B$3))`
2. Fill Formula down to *D3,* then over to *E3.*

If you want to destructively replace your original sorted data, then proceed to optional step 3:

3. Select+Copy *D1:E3* --> Paste as values in *A1.*

---

*Explanation of formula*:

There are two key parts to understanding this formula.

1. `(A1>$A$1:$B$3)` generates an array of Boolean values: `TRUE` for values in A1:B3 that at are less than A1, `FALSE` for those greater than A1. Since this array is being divided in the formula, Excel converts these Boolean values to ones and zeros.
2. `SUMPRODUCT(1/COUNTIF($A$1:$B$3,$A$1:$B$3))` is a construct used to count unique values in an array. This works by weighting each value by `1/(the number of times the number appears in the array)`. This guarantees that the sum of all values associated with that value will sum to `1`. Think of it this way. If X appears *n* times and each time is counted as `1/n`, the sum of these counts will be `n*(1/n)=1`. That is, each unique value is only counted once.

So, with this in mind, consider the example formula `=SUMPRODUCT((B1>$A$1:$B$3)/COUNTIF($A$1:$B$3,$A$1:$B$3))`, which assigns the unique id `3` to the value `2000` in the example. Step by step, this is how the formula is evaluated:

1. `=SUMPRODUCT((2000>{1001,1001,1002,2000,1002,1003})/COUNTIF($A$1:$B$3,$A$1:$B$3))`
2. `=SUMPRODUCT({TRUE,TRUE,TRUE,FALSE,TRUE,TRUE}/COUNTIF($A$1:$B$3,$A$1:$B$3))`
3. `=SUMPRODUCT({TRUE,TRUE,TRUE,FALSE,TRUE,TRUE}/COUNTIF({1001,1001,1002,2000,1002,1003},$A$1:$B$3))`
4. `=SUMPRODUCT({TRUE,TRUE,TRUE,FALSE,TRUE,TRUE}/{2,2,2,1,2,1})`
5. `=SUMPRODUCT({1/2,1/2,1/2,0/1,1/2,1/1})`
6. `=3`

Comment: Magic! :) Could you please explain a bit so I can learn from the formula? I know all used functions but I don't get how they work together in this case.

Comment: Honestly, I don't know how it works either.  I made it by combining a couple other answers I found on SE  :-)  (This is the part that puzzles me: `COUNTIF($A$1:$B$3,$A$1:$B$3)`

Comment: @Excellll – based on your nick, I'm wondering whether your can explain us how the formula works. :) For me, the part `(A1>$A$1:$B$3)` is tricky, I do not understand what is the result of comparison of cell to range.

Comment: @miroxlav I edited the answer to include an explanation and example. Adam, feel free to rollback the edit if you think this is too radical of a change to your post.

Comment: @Excelll - I Love it!  That's a great explanation.

Comment: @Excellll – fantastic application of partial components. I cannot remember if I've ever seen an Excel example out of my reach like this one. Great and detailed explanation. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

1. duplicate column A into column D
2. duplicate all values of column B into column D, with their destination starting at first empty cell below column A *(now you have all values in column D)*
3. select content of column D and [remove duplicates](http://www.excel-easy.com/examples/remove-duplicates.html)
4. type value `0` into cell E1
5. type value `1` into cell E2
6. select cells E1:E2
7. double-click small square which appears at bottom-right corner of selection boundary *(sequence of numbers is now extended to last number)*
8. into cell F1 type `=VLOOKUP(A1;$D:$E;2;FALSE)`
9. focus cell G1 and press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd>
10. select cells F1:G1
11. double-click small square which appears at bottom-right corner of selection boundary

Now you have your results in columns F and G. (Ignore remaining `#N/A` values at bottom of these columns.)

Fell free to ask if something is unclear.